# Could someone please explain what this code snippet is doing?

Tags: c, macos, segmentation-fault

I am having troubles understanding this example code I found online. Could you please help me out in understanding this

```
#define PKTNAME     "Msg"
FILE *data;       
char outMsg[1500]="getmybw\0";

data = fopen(PKTNAME,"r");
printf("file open success!!\n");
if(fgets(outMsg, 1024, data))
    printf("Msg read success!\n"); 
outMsgLen = strlen(outMsg)+1;
printf("outMsgLen is: %d,\toutMsg is:\n%s\n",outMsgLen,outMsg);
```

Also when I run this code i get a segmentation fault at this line :

`if(fgets(outMsg, 1024, data))`

Comment: Also, enclose the code after your `fopen` inside this statement: `if(data != NULL)`. This will ensure that your code doesn't continue if the file was not found.

Comment: `#define PKTNAME "Msg"`

doesn't fopen create a file with name PKTNAME ??

if fopen only opens the file with the name "PKTNAME" .. where does this file has to be ?

Comment: ok i added that if statement for the error check like you suggested. That is exactly where the problem is happening. fopen isn't working. What's causing this problem?

Comment: Nope. `fopen` will return NULL if the file doesn't exist IF you specify "r" as the mode. Please read [the documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/) for better clarity. The "MSG" file will have to be in the same directory as your executable IF your program does not modify the current directory before this snippet you posted.

Comment: thanks that worked 100% .. i changed the mode to "w+" to create and update the file... thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

**First,** the code snippet **leaks memory** by assigning a pointer to a `malloc()`ated, 1025 byte long buffer to the `data` pointer, which is then reassigned the return value of `fopen()`.

**Secondly,** the code **incorrectly assumes that `fopen()` always succeeds,** prints a misleading info message to the user, then tries to read one line or at most 1023 bytes to the buffer `outMsg`.

**Thirdly,** if the call to `fgets()` succeeds, it prints the "successful" message.

**In step four,** it grabs the length to the data just read, **incorrectly assigns it to a variable of type `int`** (it should be `size_t` instead), and then uses `printf()` to display the length and the message to the console.

---

In short, whoever provided you with this piece of "sample code" should be permanently banned from programming.

Comment: sorry i just edited my original post .. i tried fixing the code a little myself .. i got rid of malloc and i still get a segmentation fault

I am still a noob at programming so, could you please give me ways to fix this

Comment: @sukhvir No, unless you used a debugger.

Comment: i did use the debugger ..  this is the debug error :

Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KER_INVALID_ADDRESS at address :0x0000000000000068
0x00007fff9126e3a5 in fgets()

Comment: @sukhvir Stacktrace, etc.?